# Where to find Site Id for facebook connect

Tags: javascript

While setting up facebook connection in my website page. I need to put app id and site id. I am unable to get site id. Please help me from where i will get site id?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using facebook connect for some time now, but mostly it only requires an App Id and Secret key. Is your site a CMS website? Are you using a plugin?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! No my website is not CMS website. I need site id for the facebook connect coding and to run a Java script. Do you have any idea about the site id and for facebook connect where i need to put secret key?